# Dart convention for assigning doubles

Tags: flutter, dart, integer, double, conventions

Is there a convention in dart for assigning doubles?

I mean, a guide which says about which style is preferred between

```dart
double aDoubleValue = 200;
```

and

```dart
double aDoubleValue = 200.0;
```

[This page](https://dart.dev/guides/language/numbers) has a write up on Number data types but doesn't have any conventions / recommendations.

Comment: FWIW, there is a [`prefer_int_literals` lint](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_int_literals.html) (and no corresponding one for opposite stance).

Comment: Thank you @jamesdlin, I was looking for something exactly like this but for doubles.. I can refer to this while suggesting the same for doubles as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of style guidelines on this exact question but if you do

```
var aDoubleValue = 200;
```

aDoubleValue will actually be an int. So stylistically I would expect and prefer

```
double aDoubleValue = 200.0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, @jwehrle. I understand the benefits of the style, but I'm looking for a reference that I can use to convey the same to fellow developers. :)

Answer (score 0):

in dart doc for number its mentioned that

" In Java, the float and double types for fractional values were originally designed to strictly follow IEEE 754 on all platforms, but this constraint was loosened almost immediately for efficiency reasons (strictfp is required for exact coherence)."

if you follow the IEEE 754 according to this link you will find they use it like

link: https://csawesome.runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/csawesome/Unit1-Getting-Started/topic-1-3-variables.html

double aDoubleValue = 200.0;

though its actually for java,but i also prefer to declare double like this.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for, if it exists, will be found here: [Effective Dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/). I'll specifically point out [this](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#types) part which has to do with type inferencing, and [this](https://dart.dev/guides/language/type-system#type-inference) other page which says why type inferencing is useful.

I'd argue that neither of your examples is correct. You're assigning a literal float value at declaration. For that reason, using `var` and type inferencing is the best move. Do this:

```dart
var aDoubleValue = 200.0;
```

The code will be correctly inferred as a double. The `final` keyword may be appropriate instead depending on your use. There's no point in writing the word "double" when you can just look to the end of the line and see the `200.0` sitting there.

Comment: In the second (this) reference, it is explained about the type inference, but I couldn't understand why it is more useful than explicit type declaration. Could you please add a bit more explanation may be, for the answer please (why inferencing is better than being explicit)? It would be great if there are any other references also.

Comment: Type inferencing is not supposed to be more useful than explicit typing; in fact it's supposed to have the exact same end result. Using either `var` or `double` will both result in a double in `(var/double) myVar = 10.0`. Type inferencing just makes code easier to write and easier to read. Look at the specific example code given [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#dont-redundantly-type-annotate-initialized-local-variables). Really look and see which sample is easier to read. Then imagine which is easier to write.